# How can I delete all files starting with ._ from the shell in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, raspberry-pi

As the title really. I have copied over a number of files to a Raspberry Pi from a Mac. This has resulted in lots of superfluous files starting with the prefix `._`. I want to delete every file in a folder that starts with `._`. How would I do this?

Comment: Why not delete file and folders? Any further use of keeping empty folder?

Comment: The folder contains about 500 files that I want and 500 files prefixed with `._`

Comment: ok so files prefixed with ._ needs to be deleted from your folder xyz say?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try something like:

```
cd /path/to/directory; \rm -rf ._*
```

OR if there are recursive files with in subfolders then try:

```
find /path/to/directory -name "._*" -type f -print0| xargs -0 \rm -rf
```

Comment: You could simplify your find command like this: `find /path/to/directory -name "._*" -type f -delete` I've found this to be a lot quicker as it doesn't spawn an extra process for each file that has to be deleted.

Answer (score 8):

The EASY WAY:

to remove files starting with a string like : example-1.html, example-2.js, ...

```
 rm examp*
```

to remove directories starting with a string like : example-1/, example-1-1-0/, example-2/, ...

```
rm -rf examp*
```

PS:

-r for recursively

-f for force (the erasing as used for not empty directories)

that's all folks!