# How can I delete all files in all subdirectories with a certain name?

Tags: bash, shell

I have been trying to use the command line to delete all files in all subdirectories with the name s_1_1102_c.jpg.

This question is similar to what I need [How to remove folders with a certain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032701/how-to-remove-folders-with-a-certain-name) but it is removing directories and I only want to delete the files with the name s_1_1102_c.jpg.

I will need to remove this file from 260 subdirectories under the L001 directory.  My directory structure is like this:

```
L001
    C5.1
        s_1_1101_a.jpg
        s_1_1101_c.jpg
        s_1_1101_g.jpg
        s_1_1101_t.jpg
        s_1_1102_a.jpg
        s_1_1102_c.jpg
        s_1_1102_g.jpg
        s_1_1102_t.jpg
        s_1_1103_a.jpg
        s_1_1103_c.jpg
        s_1_1103_g.jpg
        s_1_1103_t.jpg
    C6.1
        s_1_1101_a.jpg
        s_1_1101_c.jpg
        s_1_1101_g.jpg
        s_1_1101_t.jpg
        s_1_1102_a.jpg
        s_1_1102_c.jpg
        s_1_1102_g.jpg
        s_1_1102_t.jpg
        s_1_1103_a.jpg
        s_1_1103_c.jpg
        s_1_1103_g.jpg
        s_1_1103_t.jpg
```

Ultimately I need to remove several files from all subdirectories (s_1_1101_g.jpg, s_1_1101_t.jpg, s_1_1102_a.jpg, s_1_1102_c.jpg, s_1_1102_g.jpg, s_1_1102_t.jpg).  So maybe there is a way to provide a list of the file names I need to delete.

How can I delete these files?

Comment: `rm L001/*/s_1_1102_c.jpg`?

Comment: `rm -f $(for f in in s_1_1101_g.jpg s_1_1101_t.jpg s_1_1102_a.jpg s_1_1102_c.jpg s_1_1102_g.jpg s_1_1102_t.jpg; do find . -name $f; done) ` if there are not more than maybe a hundred (command line length issues)

Comment: I found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331548/how-can-i-delete-all-files-starting-with-from-the-shell-in-linux and can delete all of the same single file in my subdirectories using find /hpc/home/L001 -name "s_1_1102_c.jpg" -type f -delete
Is there a way to expand this to remove all files in all subdirectories from a list of file names?

Comment: @aminards Yeah, do that in a for loop with a simple list of file names as in my example. `for f in name1 name2 name3; do find /hpc/home/L* -name $f -delete; done`

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. General Linux usage questions should be posted to [unix.se] or [su] instead.

Comment: @Cyrus I didn't know bash would substitute entire directories like that. Interesting!

Comment: @Peter - Reinstate Monica  thanks for the help.  That worked.  The syntax to add all of my file names was what ultimately helped.

Answer (score 7):

```
find . -name "s_1_1102_c.jpg" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Note: This will find and delete the file in any subdirectory of the current one. So you could execute it in `L001` or wherever else you want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in s_1_1101_g.jpg s_1_1101_t.jpg s_1_1102_a.jpg s_1_1102_c.jpg s_1_1102_g.jpg s_1_1102_t.jpg; do
  echo rm L001/*/"$i";
done
```

If output looks fine, remove `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

The final method I used to delete my files was given by `@Peter - Reinstate Monica`

```
for f in s_1_1101_t.jpg s_1_1102_a.jpg s_1_1102_c.jpg s_1_1102_g.jpg s_1_1102_t.jpg s_1_1103_a.jpg s_1_1103_c.jpg s_1_1103_g.jpg s_1_1103_t.jpg s_1_1104_a.jpg s_1_1104_c.jpg s_1_1104_g.jpg s_1_1104_t.jpg s_1_2101_g.jpg s_1_2101_t.jpg s_1_2102_a.jpg s_1_2102_c.jpg s_1_2102_g.jpg s_1_2102_t.jpg s_1_2103_a.jpg s_1_2103_c.jpg s_1_2103_g.jpg s_1_2103_t.jpg s_1_2104_g.jpg s_1_2104_t.jpg; do find /hpc/home/L001 -name $f -delete; done
```

I was concerned that my file list would be too long but it worked in this situation.

Comment: or `find /hpc/home/L001 -name s_1_1101_t.jpg -name s_1_1102_a.jpg -delete`